# Info about neo4j & spatial plug in

Tags: indexing, neo4j, spatial

Sorry for my english 
Im a new user here, and I have saw information about neo4j, 
Im using Neo4j 1.9 and now i install a spatial plugin

http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.9-neo4j-1.8.2/

only puts it in /plugins .

But where I can see examples about to use it (SPATIAL plug in). I need info about indexes, uses de withindidstance, ect. Im C# Programmer only, or info about spatial indexes in Neo4j (cypher).

Thank you ..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java, use version: [0.11-neo4j-1.9](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-spatial/0.11-neo4j-1.9/)

But if you just want to add the spatial plugin to your server, checkout:

Download [this pre-built binary](http://dist.neo4j.org.s3.amazonaws.com/spatial/neo4j-spatial-0.11-neo4j-1.9-server-plugin.zip), and unzip it in your server's `plugin` directory:

Spatial Manual on: http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/

More info on: http://neo4j.org/develop/spatial

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, 
I have installed Spatial Plug In. 

How to neo4j can accept this query or make indexes

start n=node:node_auto_index('withinDistance:[44.44, 33.32, 5.0]') return n

its returns 
Invalid query

org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'withinDistance:[44.44, 33.32, 5.0]': Encountered "  "5.0 "" at line 1, column 30.
Was expecting:
    "]" ...
    
Sorry i dont use JAVA, only C# Net, and i use a Client NET, something about Cypher. I can make Nodes, relations, etc, but now im traying with Spatial (but i cant make it work )


Thanks again.

Comment: The only way to make layers o indexes spatial is in JAVA?
can use only cypher?
Thank you

Comment: You can't use cypher to create classic indexes, since Cypher does not support it. However, you can do it via the exposed REST API, see https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/SpatialPluginFunctionalTest.java#L93